# PHP MySQL multiple table relationship not showing

Tags: mysql, relationship

I have 3 tables.

Table 1 is information about a user or customer.
Table 2 is the schedule and activity set by the user or customer.
Table 3 (Activity) is the activity table.
Tickets will count how many have the same time and same activity from the database

Desired Output

```
+-------+------------+----------+
| time  |  act_name  | Tickets  |
+-------+------------+----------+
| 10:00 |  Jump      |     2    |
| 10:00 |  Run       |     1    |
| 11:00 |  Walk      |     1    |
| 12:00 |  Run       |     2    |
+-------+------------+----------+
```

Table 1

```
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | Joe  |
|    2 | Tony |
+------+------+
```

Table 2

```
+------+--------+------------+------------+--------+
| id   | act_id | tbl_id     |     date   |  time  |
+------+--------+------------+------------+--------+
|    1 |  1     |  1         | 03/03/2022 |  10:00 |
|    2 |  2     |  1         | 03/03/2022 |  10:00 |
|    3 |  3     |  1         | 03/03/2022 |  11:00 |
|    4 |  1     |  2         | 03/03/2022 |  11:00 |
|    5 |  2     |  2         | 03/03/2022 |  12:00 |
|    6 |  2     |  1         | 03/03/2022 |  12:00 |
|    7 |  1     |  2         | 03/03/2022 |  10:00 |
+------+--------+------------+------------+--------+
```

Activity

```
+------+----------+
| id   | act_name |
+------+----------+
|    1 | Jump     |
|    2 | Run      |
|    3 | Walk     |
+------+----------+
```

I wanted to display the information group by Activity name but if they have a different time set, they should be separated. This is what I did so far but it's not right since it's showing lots of activity names from the same time set but with different users.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    tbl1.*, 
    tbl2.*, 
    act.act_name 
FROM table1 as tbl1 
LEFT JOIN table2 as tbl2 ON tbl1 .id = tbl2.booking_id 
LEFT JOIN activity as act ON act.id = tbl2.activity_id 
WHERE 
    tbl2.date = '03/03/2022'
GROUP BY tbl2.time, tbl2.id
ORDER by tbl2.time ASC
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please never store date data as varchar.  Why are you using GROUP BY, but no aggregate functions in the select?  Offering a Db-fiddle would entice mobile-device contributors (such as myself) to try to help with a resolution.  You are referencing table alias `a` in your SELECT, but you never declare an `a` table alias.  What errors are you receiving?  Likewise, there is no `bd` table alias declared.

Comment: @mickmackusa sorry I'm still new to mysql. I'm still learning.

Comment: @mickmackusa I have updated my post. those were just typos.  Currently, don't have errors. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: What is the id field in the desired output? If you are aggregating through group by, you cannot really retain PK values. What does the tickets column mean in the desired output? Is this the number of tickets per activity and time? If so, what's got table 1 to do with the question?

Comment: @Shadow sorry! out of habit from copy and paste. The id should not be a problem since I don't need the id from here. Tickets will count how many have the same time and same activity from the database. And table 1 is unnecessary. Thank you for your questions. Will update the post.

Comment: `Tickets will count` - count() function, `have the same time and same activity` - fields you group by on.